# How to use e.g. CO₂ as a label on Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

Having Django 1.6 running on Python 2.7 I'm a bit confused how to print sub numbers. E.g. On CO₂ (not sure whether this is even the correct one).

On HTML I'd do a `<sub>2</sub>`, but this is not working. When using ₂ I'm getting `Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ...`

My field for the form look like

```
class RTForm(forms.Form): 
# ...
      CO2 = forms.DecimalField(label=u"CO₂ (ppm)",
            min_value=350,
            max_value=517,
            required=False)
# ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line on top of module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 1):

Define [source code encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) at the top level in your `forms.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```